# awk how to print whole column if match

Tags: regex, awk

This is `data.txt`:

```
+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+
| Hostname                   | Plan    | Server            |
+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+
| hostname1                  | B20C120 | R1SG7.myfqdn.com  |
| another-host-name          | B40G66  | R1DC8.myfqdn.com  |
| the-other-hostname-is-here | B180G22 | R1SG8.myfqdn.com  |
| last.mydomain.com          | B400C88 | R1DG10.myfqdn.com |
+----------------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

This is my `awk` command:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF>3 {
  match($3, "B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9}", plan);
  match($4, "R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\\.myfqdn\\.com", server);
  match($2, "[a-zA-Z0-9 -.]{1,99}", server_name);
  if (plan[1] != server[1])
    print "wrong server ==> plan:", plan[0] ",", "server:", server[0] ", server_name:" server_name[0]
}' data.txt
```

This is current output when I run (it is expected and fine):

```
wrong server ==> plan: B20C120, server: R1SG7.myfqdn.com, server_name: hostname1
wrong server ==> plan: B40G66, server: R1DC8.myfqdn.com, server_name: another-host-name
wrong server ==> plan: B400C88, server: R1DG10.myfqdn.com, server_name: last.mydomain.com
```

The logic of the above `txt` and `awk` is:

> Plan names have either C or G in their name (after B, B is always the first letter), and server names after R1S or R1D, have either C or G.

> For example if Plan is B20C120 and the server is R1SG7, then since C and G don't match, then it's a wrong plan server.

> But B180G22 is in R1SG8 and that's correct.

My current `awk` command has this issue in my mind:

1. The `server` is is printed but I have to write a regex.

I tried this in my `awk`:

```
  match($2, server_name);
```

but got this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:6: (FILENAME=data.txt FNR=4) fatal: attempt to use scalar `server_name' as an array
```

Also tried this:

```
  match($2, "(.*)", server_name);
```

but for this, I got the current output with the above line.

**Expected**

is to make the `server_name` better.

Comment: Turn *off* tabular output when querying a database from the shell. It will eliminate all of the extraneous formatting. You can specify csv output making things even easier.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, but can you hint me regarding your comment how to do?

Comment: for MySQL or MariaDB use `-s` or `--silent` (e.g. `mysql -Bse "some query"`) you use `-r` or `--raw` for the same effect AND to disable escaping of control characters. For Postgres, use `-tA` to disable tabulation, column heading and alignment (e.g. `psql -tAc "some query"`) You can use `--csv` to specify comma separated output. The man-page for each details the options. If you use another database, just check the man-page for similar options for your database. They all have them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin aha thanks, but the output is not any SQL output.

Comment: Well, see if whatever it is has similar options for output `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk` solution:

```bash
cat parse.awk

BEGIN {
   FS = "\\s*[|]\\s*"
}
NF > 3 {
  server_name = $2
  match($3, /^B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9}$/, plan);
  match($4, /^R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.myfqdn\.com$/, server);
  if (plan[1] != server[1])
    print "wrong server ==> plan:", plan[0] ",", "server:", server[0] ", server_name:", server_name
}
```

Then use it as:

```bash
awk -f parse.awk file

wrong server ==> plan: B20C120, server: R1SG7.myfqdn.com, server_name: hostname1
wrong server ==> plan: B40G66, server: R1DC8.myfqdn.com, server_name: another-host-name
wrong server ==> plan: B400C88, server: R1DG10.myfqdn.com, server_name: last.mydomain.com
```

**Details:**

- `FS = "[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*"` sets `FS` as `|` surrounded by optional spaces on both sides
- Used regex literals `/.../` instead of string as regex.
- For more precise & correct matching used anchors `^` and `$` in regex.
- Now with the correct `FS` we don't need to use any regex to set `server_name`, just `$2` assignment is good enough

---

To use this directly from `bash` command line use:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {
   FS = "\\s*[|]\\s*"
}
NF>3 {
  server_name = $2
  match($3, /^B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9}$/, plan);
  match($4, /^R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.myfqdn\.com$/, server);
  if (plan[1] != server[1])
    print "wrong server ==> plan:", plan[0] ",", "server:", server[0] ", server_name:", server_name
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the provided code, it fixed my issue:) How can I use this `awk` code inside of a `bash` file without using external `awk` file? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes very much possible. Let me update answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the `awk ' ... }'` but I forgot to add `data.txt` at the end and I was surprised why it doesn't work:( Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. I have edited post with these suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `awk` code. This approach uses only 1 single array with capturing groups of Only those values which are required to be matched.

***Detailed explanation of code:***

- Using regex `^\|[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+\|[[:space:]](B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9})[[:space:]]+\|[[:space:]]+(R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.myfqdn\.com)` in `match` function here.
- It creates 5 capturing groups in this regex if there is a TRUE match for the line.
- This saves all capturing groups values into an array named `values`.
- Indexes of the array will start from 1 to 5 eg: `values[1]` for the 1st capturing group.

```
awk '
match($0,/^\|[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+\|[[:space:]](B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9})[[:space:]]+\|[[:space:]]+(R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.myfqdn\.com)/,values){
  if(values[3]!=values[5]){
     print "wrong server ==> plan: " values[2] " , server: " values[4] ", server_name: " values[1]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** as per Ed sir's comment `[^[:space:]]` could be simply written as `\S` and `[[:space:]]` as `\s` in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/^\|\s+(\S+)\s+\|\s(B[0-9]{1,3}([CG])[0-9]{1,9})\s+\|\s+(R[0-9]{1,2}[DS]([CG])[0-9]{1,3}\.myfqdn\.com)/,values){
  if(values[3]!=values[5]){
     print "wrong server ==> plan: " values[2] " , server: " values[4] ", server_name: " values[1]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Sample output will be as follows:

```
wrong server ==> plan: B20C120 , server: R1SG7.myfqdn.com, server_name: hostname1
wrong server ==> plan: B40G66 , server: R1DC8.myfqdn.com, server_name: another-host-name
wrong server ==> plan: B400C88 , server: R1DG10.myfqdn.com, server_name: last.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Yep, nice solution. Keep fighting the good fight!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you sir, always nice to hear from you sir cheers :)

Comment: Since that requires GNU awk anyway for the third arg to `match()` you could change every `[[:space:]]` to `\s` and `[^[:space:]]` to `\S` for brevity if you like.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir for letting know. I will change it in sometime cheers sir.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir have done the changes now, cheers.